# I'm trying to dockerize my node app using docker file.But it is throwing an error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'

Tags: node.js, docker

### Docker File For MY Node app:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

# WORKDIR specifies the application directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copying package.json file to the app directory
COPY node-express/package.json /app

# Installing npm for DOCKER
RUN npm install

# Copying rest of the application to app directory
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 3000

# Starting the application using npm start
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

### MY LOG FILE:

```
> hello-world@1.0.0 start /app
> node app.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'
```

### MY Application Root Directory Structure:

app.js  node_modules  npm-debug.log  package.json  package-lock.json  test

Comment: You're `COPY`ing a file in a `node-express` directory, but that does not exist in your directory structure. So it looks like you are running `docker build` from somewhere else, and thus your `app.js` will not be found in the `COPY . /app` line.

Comment: Instead of "." try to give the absolute path, else the directory which you run matters which creates bottleneck most of the time.

Comment: wmorrell please can you elaborate your answer.That will b very helpfull

Comment: In node-express Directory.I have  files and folders like (app.js, node_modules, npm-debug.log, package.json, package-lock.json, test).

Comment: Have you examined the filesystem inside the container?  Are the `app.js`, `package.json` and `node_modules` where you expect them to be?

Comment: David Maze yes i do